# Proxy Error: Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache, server, proxy

I am fetching a report from my apache including a 41000 rows data report and it gives me following error. I checked the logs and there is no exception there:

Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /reporting/cards/TransactionHistory_cp_trd_trid1.rpt.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

But when I fetched about 20000 rows, it fetched perfectly.

Comment: Invalid response, so probably not a timeout issue.  There could be something wrong with the file, or with the server that sends it.  Have you tried sending the file from row 20000 to the end only?  Check the logs from the sending server, this one might be timing out.